# C++ method overriding when using parent type

Tags: c++, vector, overriding

Heyo, I'm a little confused about how method overriding works when you involve calling objects as their parent type.

Here is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "Made A.\n";
    }
    void doThing() {
        std::cout << "A did a thing.\n";
    };
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
        std::cout << "Made B.\n";
    }
    void doThing() {
        std::cout << "B did a thing.\n";
    };
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C() {
        std::cout << "Made C.\n";
    }
    void doThing() {
        std::cout << "C did a thing.\n";
    };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Make objects: \n";
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    std::cout << "Call objects normally: \n";
    a.doThing();
    b.doThing();
    c.doThing();

    std::cout << "Call objects as their parent type from a vector: \n";
    vector<A> vect;
    vect.push_back(a); vect.push_back(b); vect.push_back(c);

    for(int i=0;i<vect.size();i++)
        vect.data()[i].doThing();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output I get:

```
Make objects: 
Made A.
Made A.
Made B.
Made A.
Made C.
Call objects normally: 
A did a thing.
B did a thing.
C did a thing.
Call objects as their parent type from a vector: 
A did a thing.
A did a thing.
A did a thing.
```

This same code in another language (like Java) would produce this output:

```
Make objects: 
Made A.
Made B.
Made C.
Call objects normally: 
A did a thing.
B did a thing.
C did a thing.
Call objects as their parent type from a vector: 
A did a thing.
B did a thing.
C did a thing.
```

**In short, how do I achieve that second output in c++?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you pass a `Derived` object by value to a function taking a `Base`, something called "slicing" happens. Basically, only the `Base` part of the `Derived` object is being used.

You need to pass the object by reference or by pointer to avoid these issues. For example, declaring

```
f(Base&)
```

allows passing in a `Derived` object, i.e. allows you to write

```
f(Derived)
```

In addition, to enable run-time polymorphism, your function must be marked `virtual`. Java by default has everything implicitly marked virtual. However, this is C++ and you don't pay for what you don't use (virtual functions are an overhead).

PS: in your code, even if you want, you cannot use a `std::vector` of references. However, you can wrap the objects using `std::reference_wrapper` which allows you to "simulate" a `std::vector` of references:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> vect
```

and use the `get` member function to retrieve the reference

```
for(int i=0;i<vect.size();i++)
    vect[i].get().doThing();
```

Or, perhaps simpler, just use a `std::vector<A*>`

Comment: Righo! Changing to "vector<A*> vect;" and pushing data as "vect.push_back(&b);" results in the output I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `virtual` keyword to enable functions to be overwritten in subclasses.

Comment: That's part of it. You also can't get polymorphism with values, so the vector would have to store pointers.

Comment: I changed my code to virutal void doThing() but it still outputs the same thing. Is there a specific way of using virtual?

Comment: @newObjekt: See my comment. While Java always uses references in dealing with object types, C++ can use object values. But when you assign a derived class value to a base class value, you lose the derived object information. This is called [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/10077).

Answer (score 1):

Ok So here is what's happening:
Make objects:
A is quite obvious I think. The A object gets constructed and its default constructor prints

```
Made A
```

When you instantiate a B object first its parent class gets constructed fully. So in this case the parent class is A it gets constructed with the default constructor, which prints out

```
Made A
```

After that the B class remaining part gets constructed and runs its constructor which prints out

```
Made B
```

The same thing happens when instantiating C

Calling functions on the objects:
Its just a simple function call and since you overwrite the function in each class they get called and not the parent's function.

When you create a vector of the objects you copy the objects into them since you dont pass the reference nor the pointer. You have not written a copy constructor so the default bit by bit copy will run. This way from a B class object you get an A class object which function will print out A did thing and not B did thing. Same happens with C.